# How should I make my getMove() method interact with my GUI in my chess application?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm developing an application in Java to help me land my first job as a junior developer. It's a chess game with a GUI that both human players click on from the same machine.

When it's, say, white's turn to move, the application calls white's `getMove(Interface interaction)` method until a valid `MoveAttempt` is returned. Here's the `getMove(Interface interaction)` method of `HumanPlayer`:

```
public MoveAttempt getMove(Interface interaction) {
    while(!interaction.selectionMade()) {

    }

    byte pieceFile = interaction.getPenultimateFile();
    byte pieceRank = interaction.getPenultimateRank();
    byte toFile = interaction.getUltimateFile();
    byte toRank = interaction.getUltimateRank();
    return new MoveAttempt(pieceFile, pieceRank, toFile, toRank, getIsWhite());
}
```

`penultimateFile`, `penultimateRank`, `ultimateFile` and `ultimateRank` are supposed to store the file (column) and rank (row) of the last two chess tiles clicked. This is achieved through this `actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)` which `Interface` has because it implements `ActionListener`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    LocalizedButton button = (LocalizedButton) event.getSource();

    if(penultimateFile == -1) {
       penultimateFile = button.getFile();
       penultimateRank = button.getRank();
    }
    else {
        ultimateFile = button.getFile();
        ultimateRank = button.getRank();
    }
}
```

and by calling this method before each call to `getMove(Interface interaction)`

```
public void resetClicks() {
    penultimateFile = -1;
    penultimateRank = -1;
    ultimateFile = -1;
    ultimateRank = -1;
}
```

So the idea is that a move attempt is not made until someone has clicked on two chess squares which is why I have a while loop indefinitely calling `selectionMade()`:

```
public boolean selectionMade() {
    return penultimateFile != -1 && penultimateRank != -1 && ultimateFile != -1 && ultimateRank != -1;
}
```

This didn't work---pieces didn't move---so in an attempt to see what was happening I put this print statement

```
System.out.println(interaction.getPenultimateFile() + ", " +
                interaction.getPenultimateRank() + ", " +
                interaction.getUltimateFile() + ", " +
                interaction.getUltimateRank());
```

into the while loop to see what was going on and now it works---pieces move---except I may have encountered times in which it didn't work but I last I tried I couldn't get it to fail.

**I don't want to print anything to the console; what should I do in lieu of having this while loop?**

Edit: Putting `boolean lol = 0` just above the loop and `lol = !lol` in the loop doesn't allow the code to work. Neither does calling `doNothing()`.

Edit: Here's the source code: https://github.com/JosephBGriffith/Chess
Right now only the pawns work because I have other bugs that I need to fix. En passant works except the opponent piece doesn't get eliminated.

Comment: Random aside: try to avoid naming a class `Interface` (or any variant of a keyword).

Comment: @Rogue Yeah, I noticed that, but decided to be a thug anyway. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: What actions does the user need to perform in order to make the pieces move (but they don't)? The `while` loop may be freezing the GUI. Have you read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) ?

Comment: @Abra I know nothing about Concurrency. My Swing and AWT knowledge is very limited.

Comment: hey @JosephGriffith this is interesting, do you have any way that us contributors could interact with this code more? (ie a git repo?)

Comment: @bartius Posted a link in an edit

Comment: *"Here's the source code:"* Don't post the code at external links - all code should be in the question itself. And by 'all the code' I mean a [mre], rather than the entire code currently being used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, I added it in response to bartius's comment, not because I thought it was necessary to answer the question.

Comment: sorry about that too, thanks for the correction @AndrewThompson. I think that tgdavies has it right though, you should do something along the lines of setting the penultimate and ultimate rank/file in a jbutton object, rather than looping until you receive the values.

Answer (score 0):

I would invert the control, so that the UI pushes moves to the game, rather than the game trying to pull moves from the UI.

So your game class might have:

```
class Game {
  boolean move(int fromFile, int fromRank, int toFile, int toRank) { ... }
  ...
}
```

If the move wasn't legal (e.g. if it was the other player's turn) then `move` returns false and the move doesn't occur. That is, the internal state of the Game is unchanged.

And your `actionPerformed` method becomes:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    LocalizedButton button = (LocalizedButton) event.getSource();

    if(penultimateFile == -1) {
       penultimateFile = button.getFile();
       penultimateRank = button.getRank();
    }
    else {
        game.move(penultimateFile, penultimateRank, button.getFile(), button.getRank());
        penultimateFile = -1;
    }
}
```

You could use the return value of `move` to provide some feedback to the user if the move is illegal.

Something to note about this suggestion is that `move` is executed on the Swing event thread. In theory this is bad practice, although unless your `move` method is very slow it won't matter.

Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html and consider whether you want to use `invokeLater`.